# What is the use of the title attribute on a html element?

Tags: html

What is the use of the title attribute on a html element?

```
<div class="myDiv" title="This is the title"> Stuff </div>
```

Is it intended to be used as a tooltip? Does it have any further use?

Comment: Is there something wrong with [the manual](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-title-attribute)?

Comment: @Quentin, nothing at all. I was unaware of the existence of http://www.w3.org/. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much. The HTML spec calls it [advisory text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-title-attribute), but it uses the word "tooltip" as well, because that's how it is typically represented:

> The `title` attribute represents advisory information for the element, such as would be appropriate for a tooltip. On a link, this could be the title or a description of the target resource; on an image, it could be the image credit or a description of the image; on a paragraph, it could be a footnote or commentary on the text; on a citation, it could be further information about the source; on interactive content, it could be a label for, or instructions for, use of the element; and so forth. The value is text.

Its role in relation to the content depends entirely on the context given by the content, but in general it serves as optional, supplementary information for that content.

Comment: Is it good idea/practice to use it for passing values? Let's say for example, in jQuery, for passing a variable value to some event in a form.

Comment: @carloswm85: No - use a data attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Title attribute is for tool tip. IN title attribute we can pass some text to tell the user for what purpose that particular element is.

Answer (score 1):

This topic is already well explained. But it is important to remember that using the title attribute is not very useful when it comes to HTML accessibility and usability. The use of this attribute is neither recommended by W3C. In [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#the-title-attribute) words:

> Relying on the title attribute is currently discouraged as many user
>   agents do not expose the attribute in an accessible manner as required
>   by this specification (e.g., requiring a pointing device such as a
>   mouse to cause a tooltip to appear, which excludes keyboard-only users
>   and touch-only users, such as anyone with a modern phone or tablet).

Answer (score 0):

If you give an object a Title, try hovering your mouse over it, It will show a subtext which contains the text you set as title.

Answer (score 0):

"The title attribute allows the author to provide extra information about any element on a page."

Typically, this attribute’s content is rendered as a tooltip that appears when the user hovers the cursor over the element to which the title is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.. It is mainly intended for tooltip... But also we are using for identification.. Whenever two or more divisions are placed one behind other, to identify each one we can use that.....

Answer (score 0):

The `title` attribute is a descriptor, like the `alt` attribute for images. It is not required, but would be good practice to use where it makes sense. An old school example might be if you have a table of information on your page. Adding the *title* attribute to the table tag with a brief notation of what the table is (e.g. 2014 Daytona 500 Race Results) would make sense.

Once upon a time, search engines treated the contents of *title* attributes as content. I don't believe they do anymore (though I'm not 100% sure) though.

Hope that helps!